# Who are the other 2 people?

Tags: discussion, questions

Every time I post a question, either on Meta or SE, as soon as I post it I see that it has been seen by 3 people.  I'm assuming I'm 1 of them, but who are these other 2 people who view my question the millisecond I post it?  No matter what time of day, they're feverishly hawking my every post.  Waiting.  Watching.  Disapproving...

Comment: Hiya!!! *waves*

Comment: You, Bart and T. Internet

Comment: @rene T. Internet also more commonly goes by the name "Google".  Google is always watching.  Always.  Google and Bart.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ ಠ_ಠ ಠ_ಠ ಠ_ಠ ಠ_ಠ

Comment: You must have dedicated followers (or are targeted by the NSA). I often see "1 view" by my questions initially.

Comment: Caching. It's always... oh, wait...

Comment: That would be Obama and Obama's clone.

Comment: It's the famous trinity. In the first person, it's "Me, myself, and I".

Comment: Why you insist on keeping the title vague?

Answer (score 29):

The other two people are two people who have looked at the question.

That is all.  Thank you for playing.

(posting an answer to get this off the front page.  Please upvote; it's CW).

Comment: You anti-fun fun nazis!

Comment: I agree with Richard. What do you have against fun fun nazis? They're so fun, they're fun fun!

Comment: [You forgot the theme music to your answer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGugFsDHeF4&t=10m29s)

Answer (score 26):

Do you have "internet security" software, or perhaps anti-porn software on your computer?

Some instances of both of these types of software will fetch a web page at the same time as, or even slightly before, you do, and analyze it for (malware|porn) and only if it passes will they let your web browser finally fetch it. These additional requests may or may not come from your own IP address; they may come from the software company's network. (And of course the company is aware of every URL you visit...)